# How to initialize an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

Hey i'm trying to initialize an array in c# and don't know why this doesn't work

```
Wave currentWave = new Wave(
                                {
                                    {1, 1, 1}, 
                                    {1, 1},
                                    {1, 1, 1}
                                }, 
                                    {3, 2}
                                );

private class Wave {
    private int currentLoad;
    private int[] aTimesToNextLoad;
    private int[][] aEnemieLoads;

    public Wave(int[][] aEnemiesToLoad, int[] aTimesToNextLoad) {
        this.aEnemieLoads     = aEnemieLoads;
        this.aTimesToNextLoad = aTimesToNextLoad;
    }
}
```

I get like 18 syntax errors with this. I have also tried using `new int[][] {...}`, then i get this message:

Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead

What is the solution?

Comment: Unrelated, but `this.aEnemieLoads     = aEnemieLoads`  is wrong - the parameter is called `aEnemiesToLoad`, you're assigning the field to itself (look at compile warnings).

Answer (score 0):

Okay i still don't know why the code doesn't work but this fixed the problem.

```
Wave currentWave = new Wave(new int[][]
                            {
                                new int [] {1, 1, 1}, 
                                new int [] {1, 1},
                                new int [] {1, 1, 1}
                            }, 
                                new int [] {3, 2}
                            );
```

Comment: Note that in the question i only used 'new int' twice. One for the whole first array and one for second one.